# Pipe output to batch script

Tags: batch-file, pipe

I am using grep on windows to filter a file and would like to pipe the output to another batch script.

e.g.

```
grep "foo" bar.txt | mybatch.bat
```

and in mybatch i would like to process each matching line

e.g. mybatch.bat:

```
echo Line with foo: %1
```

on linux I can solve this via

```
grep "foo" bar.txt | while read x; do mybatch.sh $x; done
```

but no idea how I can do this on a windows machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `for`:

```
for /f %x in ('grep "foo" bar.txt') do call mybatch.cmd "%x"
```

This will call your batch file once for every non-empty line, just as your shell script example would do.

Comment: thanks, works well, I output my pipe chain into a temp file and then do the for loop on the temp file (happens in another batch file):
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('type temp.tmp') do call test.cmd "%%x"
but it adds quotes to each line that is passed to the test.cmd

so if test.cmd does echo Line is %1
I will get Line is "foo" (with quouts) while the lines in the temp file are without. any trick to get rid of the quotes?

Comment: Use `%~1` instead. But there is no need to resort to `type` in that case, `for /f %%x in (temp.tmp) do ...` does the same.

Comment: this is no pipe... the task may be done but does the question remain actually unanswered? (edit: proposed to rename the question)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick of the trade:

head.bat

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set n=%1

for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('more') do (
echo %%x
set /A n -= 1
if !n! EQU 0 exit /b
)
```

Using it:

```
REM print the first 10 lines:
type test.txt | head 10
```